# I've got a return 0 and i dont know why

Tags: php, sql

I've got a problem in my PHP code whith an SQL statement.

I want to get back the ID of my Indice where my name = 'myname'.
Here is my code :

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

try { 
    $db = new PDO("$server:host=$host;dbname=$base", $user, $passwd); 


    //Statement = INSERT INTO indice
    $stmtInd = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO indice(ID, Name, IDFormation)
        VALUES (:ID, :Name, :IDFormation)");
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':ID', $id);
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':Name', $name);
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':IDFormation', $idformation);
    //Statement = INSERT INTO note
    $stmtNote = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO note(ID, Valeur, Valeurtext, IDIndice)
        VALUES (:ID, :Valeur, :Valeurtext, :IDIndice)");
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':Valeur', $valeur);
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':Valeurtext', $valeurtext);
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':IDIndice', $IDindice);
    $noteIdindice = $db->prepare("SELECT ID FROM indice WHERE Name = :Name");
        $noteIdindice->bindParam(':Name', $name);
        $noteIdindice->execute();           
        $resultat = $noteIdindice->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
        var_dump($resultat);

    //Indice 1
    $name = "Equilibre theorie / pratique";
    $idformation = "1";
    $stmtInd->execute();

    $valeur = $_POST["indice1"];
    $valeurtext = "";
    $IDindice = $resultat['ID'];
    $stmtNote->execute();
    echo "Success";
} 
catch (PDOException $e) { 
    die("Impossible de se connecter a la source de donnees..."); 
}
?>
```

There is other Indice but you dont need it cuz its the same as "//Indice 1".

Everything works and i have no failure. But my query give me a wrong return. It returns me "0" instead of the ID i want.

Do you guys know why ?

Comment: What function you have used, to print the result ?

Comment: I dont print the result i just use fetch() to put the result in my variable $resultat

Comment: How do you know the $resultat variable = 0 if you don't print it ?

Comment: Exactly ! How do you know then ?

Comment: I see it in my database. I do an insert and it insert me 0.

Comment: can you add details of your $stmtNote. Describe the query please.

Comment: here are all my queries

Answer (score 2):

Your prepared statement is never executed, you should add execute :

```
$noteIdindice = $db->prepare("SELECT ID FROM indice WHERE Name = :Name");
$noteIdindice->bindParam(':Name', $name);
$noteIdindice->execute();//Add this row
$resultat = $noteIdindice->fetch();
```

**EDIT :**

You are trying to binding params with null values.

```
        $stmtInd = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO indice(ID, Name, IDFormation)
        VALUES (:ID, :Name, :IDFormation)");
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':ID', $id);
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':Name', $name); //$name variable not exists
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':IDFormation', $idformation);//$idformation variable not exists
```

Try to do this :

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';

try { 
    $db = new PDO("$server:host=$host;dbname=$base", $user, $passwd); 
    //Indice 1
    $name = "Equilibre theorie / pratique";
    $idformation = "1";
    $valeur = $_POST["indice1"];
    $valeurtext = "";
    //Statement = INSERT INTO indice
    $stmtInd = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO indice(ID, Name, IDFormation)
        VALUES (:ID, :Name, :IDFormation)");
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':ID', $id);
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':Name', $name);
        $stmtInd->bindParam(':IDFormation', $idformation);
        $stmtInd->execute();
    //Statement = INSERT INTO note
    $stmtNote = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO note(ID, Valeur, Valeurtext, IDIndice)
        VALUES (:ID, :Valeur, :Valeurtext, :IDIndice)");
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':ID', $ID);
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':Valeur', $valeur);
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':Valeurtext', $valeurtext);
        $stmtNote->bindParam(':IDIndice', $IDindice);
        $stmtNote->execute(); 
    $noteIdindice = $db->prepare("SELECT ID FROM indice WHERE Name = :Name");
        $noteIdindice->bindParam(':Name', $name);
        $noteIdindice->execute();           
        $resultat = $noteIdindice->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
        var_dump($resultat);

    $IDindice = $resultat['ID'];

    echo "Success";
} 
catch (PDOException $e) { 
    die("Impossible de se connecter a la source de donnees..."); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Make a `var_dump` of $resultat

Comment: How ? where ? isnt that js ?

Comment: After : `$resultat = $noteIdindice->fetch();` put `var_dump($resultat)`

Comment: i got this : C:\wamp64\www\Test\Insertion.php:55:boolean false

Comment: Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145259/ensure-that-pdo-fetch-method-result-false-is-a-error-or-empty-result

Comment: Okay. Even if i dont understand why it works perfectly thx man ! only it wont work for each indice that i want to insert.

Comment: its not completly solve but im looking for a better way to do what i want