# pdo_sqlsrv: how to recognize if fetch "false" is an error or empty recordset?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

The *fetch* method returns false both if the recordset is empty and if there is an actual error. The method described here allows you to easily recognize what is happening:

[ensure that PDO fetch method result "false" is a error or empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145259/ensure-that-pdo-fetch-method-result-false-is-a-error-or-empty-result)

It works well with pdo_mysql, however pdo_sqlsrv throws an error even when the recordset is empty. Is this the intended behaviour? Is it possible to avoid those errors?

EDIT: the error is "There are no more rows in the active result set" and it is produced when you try to fetch a recordset which is already completely fetched. This not happens with pdo_mysql, which just returns false.

EDIT 2: I have finally understood the problem more in details: the **first time** you fetch an empty recordset you get FALSE, then, if you fetch again, you get an error. This doesn't happen with pdo_mysql (and I am pretty sure it doesn't happen with PDO pgsql and sqlite either): you still get false without producing errors.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
// sqlsrv connection
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=....;Database=....", "user", "password", array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));

// mysql connection
// $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=....;dbname=....', 'user', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$sql = "drop table if exists test;";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "create table test (name varchar(10));";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "insert into test (name) values ('Alice');";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "select * from test";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

// fetch first record
$row = fetch_row_db($res);
var_dump($row);

// fetch again
$row = fetch_row_db($res);
var_dump($row);

// fetch again
$row = fetch_row_db($res);
var_dump($row);

function fetch_row_db(&$res)
{
    try {
        return $res->fetch();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error during record fetching.';
        exit();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
MySQL
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Alice" [0]=> string(5) "Alice" } bool(false) bool(false)

sqlsrv
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Alice" [0]=> string(5) "Alice" } bool(false) Error during record fetching.
```

Comment: Did you set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` as `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Comment: @GabrielHeming Yes I did.

Comment: Can you provide us more information (code, PHP version, etc...)?

Comment: PHP 7.1.1 on MacOS. I have provided more details and the code to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: if `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` does not produce exceptions on error then it's possibly an overlook in the SQLSRV driver.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález not sure what you meant, what I said is that it actually does produce exceptions even if I didn't expect that.

Comment: @Eugenio I stand corrected. PHP makes a clear distinction between good old [errors](http://php.net/trigger_error) and PHP/5+ [exceptions](http://php.net/throw) and PDO made the strange design decision of being an OOP extension that defaults to errors—thus my confusion.